# How do I use Workplace Graph API to post in a multi-company group?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

I have learnt how to use the Workplace Graph API, and I can post to the groups of Facebook Workplace, but when I try to post in a multi company Facebook workplace group, I get a permission error. How can can be done?

Comment: how to post from my app to Workplace Group using Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

You can't post in a MCG through API. 
In the MCG groups, you can just read using the token of a member of the group